# Passar uma variavel JS como parametro do Url.Action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Olá, gostaria de passar como parametro as variaveis JS, mas não esta dando certo, gostaria de saber a forma correta de fazer isto, desde já agradeço

```
 <script>
    function check() {
         var teste1 = document.getElementById("lala");
         var teste2 = document.getElementById("lala2");
         @Url.Action("Teste", "Teste", teste1);
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode misturar `javascript` com `Razor`.

Para fazer o que deseja, teria que fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
 <script>
    function check() {
         var teste1 = document.getElementById("lala");
         var teste2 = document.getElementById("lala2");
         var url = '@Url.Action("Teste", "Teste")/' + teste1;
         //Ou assim
         var url1 = '@Url.Action("Teste", "Teste")?teste=' + teste2;
    }
 </script>
```